# Relating multiplying the angle inside a sine/cosine with an operation outside the sine/cosine

Tags: geometry

Say you have sin (a) and later have sin (na) being n any real number that just multiplies the angle. Is there any equivalence between multiplying the angle of the sine and operation involving n and sin (a) but not involving sin (an) ? In other words, a formula that would state sin (an) = [...] being [...] involving n and sin (a) separately.

Comment: Google angle sum and difference formulas, and double and triple angle formulas. I think you will enjoy what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post I derive general expressions for $\cos(n\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, but bear with me because I prove Matthew Daly's claim that $\sin(n\theta)$ can be expressed in terms of $\sin \theta$ for odd $n$ by the end of the post. Consider Euler's equation $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta).$  Cosine and sine are the real and imaginary parts of Euler's formula, so
$$\cos(n \theta)=\Re(e^{i n\theta})=\Re({e^{i\theta}}^n)=\Re((\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^n)=
\\\Re(\cos^n \theta +i {n\choose 1}cos^{n-1}\theta \sin\theta-{n\choose 2}\cos^{n-2} \theta \sin^2 \theta-...+i^n \sin^n \theta)=
\\ \cos ^n \theta - {n \choose 2}\cos^{n-2} \theta \sin^2 \theta + {n \choose 4} \cos^{n-4} \theta \sin^4 \theta-...$$
and 
$$\sin(n \theta)=\Im(e^{i n\theta})=\Im({e^{i\theta}}^n)=\Im((\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^n)=
\\\Im(\cos^n \theta +i {n\choose 1}cos^{n-1}\theta \sin\theta-{n\choose 2}\cos^{n-2} \theta \sin^2 \theta-...+i^n \sin^n \theta)=
\\{n\choose 1}cos ^{n-1} \theta - {n \choose 3}cos^{n-2} \theta sin^2 \theta + {n \choose 5} \cos^{n-5} \theta \sin^5 \theta-...$$

As a relatively simple example of this process
$$\cos(3\theta)=\Re((\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^3)=\cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta$$
and
$$\sin(3\theta)=\Im((\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^3) = 3\cos^2(\theta)\sin\theta-\sin^3\theta=3(1-\sin^2\theta)\sin \theta - \sin^3 \theta=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta.$$

When $n$ is odd all of the cosine terms in the expansion of $\sin(n\theta)$ are being raised to even powers, and every instance of $cos^{2k}\theta$ can be converted to $(1-\sin^2 \theta)^k$, giving a polynomial for $\sin(n\theta)$ which is completely in terms of $\sin \theta,$ as stated by Matthew Daly.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, then yes.  For instance:

$$\sin3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$$

$$\sin5x=5\sin x-20\sin^3 x+16\sin^5x$$

and so on.  The basic form of the equation is called the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind, and you can look it up for higher values of $n$.

If $n$ is even, you can do something close, which is to have a formula in terms of $\sin x$ multiplied by a single term of $\cos x$.  For instance:
$$\sin4x=\cos x(4\sin x-8\sin^3 x)$$

That form is called a Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind